# Color data points based on data label text - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I have the code below which colors bubble chart data points based on the data label text. I'm not sure why I am keeping an "Invalid paramter error"

Edited for more clarity.

The code loops through a spreadsheet where I have data label filter critieria stored(see image attached). It will copy a pre-made bubble graph and color it.  variable f loops between variables a and c, and based on the values in between these two variables, the bubble chart will color if it matches. If not, it moves past it. After bubbles are colored, it moves on to the next variation of coloring.

```
Sub Slide31()
Dim rngx As Range
Dim rngy As Range
Dim rngz As Range
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim icnt As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim icounter As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim d As Variant
Dim Chart As ChartObject
Dim PPapp As Object
Dim PPTDoc As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPpres As Object
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppslide As Object
Dim e As Long
Dim f As Long
Dim filename As String
Dim filename2 As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant

Dim ch As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim iPoint As Long
Dim nPoint As Long


Set ws = Worksheets("Reference")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Bubbles")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Slide 31")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Bubble Reference")

ws2.Activate

'ws2.Range("h:h").NumberFormat = "0.00%"

lastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
For icounter = 1 To lastrow
For icnt = 51 To 79
If ws2.Cells(icounter, 2) = ws.Cells(icnt, 3) Then
d = ws.Cells(icnt, 3)
a = icounter + 2
b = icounter + 2
c = icounter + 11

filename = ""
filename2 = ""

ws3.ChartObjects(1).Copy
ws2.Paste

    Set ch = ActiveChart
Set s = ch.SeriesCollection(1)

For f = a To c
nPoint = s.Points.Count
For iPoint = 1 To nPoint



    If ws2.Cells(f, 8) = s.Points(iPoint).DataLabel.Text Then
        s.Points(iPoint).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)

    End If
  Next iPoint

 Next f

End If
Next icnt
Next icounter
```

Comment: Run time error : 1004, "Invalid parameter error" will happen when you try to access a point ordinal which doesn't exist. Most likely you didn't share the full code. You are obviously tweaking the series data somewhere in code after grabbing the point count. And your are not declaring Point explicitly with `Variant\Object\Point` **Interior is a perfectly valid property.**

Comment: @cyboashu which version of Excel do you have where Point.Interior doesn't raise an error? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837406(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @DavidZemens Excel -2016.

Comment: Daruki, what are values of your variables when the error raises, perhaps tht will help you narrow down the root cause.

Comment: @cyboashu wow, thanks for the screenshot. I confirm that `interior` is a valid property in Excel 2010, even though the documentation (and intellisense) do not seem to support it.

Comment: I made revision to my answer with an alternative approach, try that and see what happens

Comment: @Daruki are you icluding #N/A in your chart or excluding them? Are you trying to change color on ws2 chart or ws3 chart?

Comment: Why is it a secret which line of code throws the error?

Answer (score 3):

`Point` object doesn't have an `Interior` property. (Edit: Yes, it actually does even though the Dox and the Intellisense do not seem to expose it).

([Point object reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff847077(v=office.14).aspx) | [Excel Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx))

The specific error you're getting (1004, "Invalid parameter error") is akin to Index Out of Bounds, you're somehow trying to index the Points collection in an invalid way, though I'm not sure how this is possible. You can easily get this error if you try `s.Points(0)` or `s.Points(s.Points.Count+1)`, for instance.

You could try this alternative approach:

```
Dim pt as Point

For Each pt in s.Points
    If ws2.Cells(f, 8) = pt.DataLabel.Text Then
        pt.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, however when I run, it gets through coloring a few bubbles, then arrives at the same "invalid parameter error"

Comment: Need more information from you. At this point, I don't know what I need though... please add screenshot of your chart type, and provide sample data which will exhibit the failure.  It will also help if you can debug the values of your variables when the error raises and include that information above, too.

Comment: Thank you David for trying to help. At this point I'm pressed for time and your above revision didn't work. I'll revisit this problem tomorrow. In the mean time I will manually color them.